# Django-rest-framework How to add additional data to request.data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using DRF & token authentication system to deal with the API. Whenever I send the data from the client it sends two of three required fields: `title` and `name`. But `created_by` is given by `request.user` in the backend.

So I need the following, that of course does not work as expected:

```py
class DefaultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint
    """
    queryset = Default.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')
    serializer_class = DefaultSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filterset_fields = ['created_by', 'title', 'name']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['created_by'] = request.user.id
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Since I can't change `request.data` object I should completely override `create` method. Therefore there is no easy way to do the previous stuff, right? or there is?

Answer (score 2):

You should override `perform_create` method which calls the save method of the serializer and send additional keyword arguments as the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) says:

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    request = serializer.context['request']
    serializer.save(created_by=request.user.id)
```

---

The original method does:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: it does not reach that method. I guess it because that `perform_create()` works in generic views but not viewsets...

Comment: Hmmm, it should... Because `viewsets.ModelViewSet` class inherits from `mixins.CreateModelMixin` and that class has the `create` and `perform_create` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think add it to your serializer class is better

```
created_by = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to handle it in the `create()` function by using [this example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) in the documentation:

```py
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = DefaultSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
        serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
        return Response({
            'data': serializer.data
        })
```